# Use Widget Button in my player inputs in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have 2 buttons in my widget blueprint for 1 input action. (Smooth Movement and Teleport)
I need when the player clicked on the one of them my input do that.
can you help me??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1495.png)

I added 2 button in my widget
and I need to set that onclicked for my character action.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention more context. The details of your character class, the relationship between the widget and the character, if you have any reference of one object in the other, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.